# Angularjs download table of data to csv

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can someone teach me how to convert a table of data from json into PDF? I can only find chunks of codes that are working without explanation. Would be cool if someone know a place where it's explained properly and share it with me. Appreciated !

Example of my table of data :

```
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th ng-click="sort('id')">Name
                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='id'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th ng-click="sort('first_name')">Block No.
                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='first_name'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th ng-click="sort('last_name')">Postal Code
                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='last_name'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                  <th ng-click="sort('hobby')">Street Name
                    <span class="glyphicon sort-icon" ng-show="sortKey=='hobby'" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up':reverse,'glyphicon-chevron-down':!reverse}"></span>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr dir-paginate="audit in auditoriums|orderBy:sortKey:reverse|filter:search|itemsPerPage:5 | limitTo: 1 - auditoriums.length">
                  <td>{{audit.NAME}}</td>
                  <td>{{audit.ADDRESSBLOCKHOUSENUMBER}}</td>
                  <td>{{audit.ADDRESSPOSTALCODE}}</td>
                  <td>{{audit.ADDRESSSTREETNAME}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: You an use this: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable

Comment: You need to improve your question. If you only want to do it with angular you should check some library like PDFKit to do it, otherwise go backend with an alternative to C# or PHP.

Comment: Thank you!! @PrerakSola

Comment: Thanks for the info @Gui

Answer (score 0):

You can try use of this [Client-side JavaScript PDF generation](http://%20https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)

```js
var doc = new jsPDF()
doc.text('Sample text', 11100221, 22,44)
doc.save('sampleText.pdf')
```